# Projective invariants of the plane and cross ratio

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry, invariant-theory

I am looking for a reference for the following admittedly imprecise statement:

> Any projective invariant of n points in the projective plane may be
> expressed as a function of well-chosen cross-ratios.

By *projective invariant* I mean a rational function defined on the set of $n$-tuple of distinct points in the projective plane on an arbitrary field $K$, invariant under the action of the projective group of transformations.
This is a folklore result that is often stated without proof (e.g. in Efimov, *higher geometry*) but I can't find a reference providing a precise statement and a proof.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but cross-ratio is usually  defined for $4$ points *on a line*. Here you have $n$ general points in  the projective plane, so I expect that non even three of them are collinear. What cross-ratios are you talking about?

Comment: @Polizzi Well, that's part of the question. For five points $A_1$... $A_5$, an explicit formula is to be found in the book of Efimov, higher geometry. The cross ratios involved depend on $A_1$, $A_5$ and one of the intersection points of the lines $A_2A_3$, $A_2A_4$ and $A_3A_4$ with $A_1A_5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the precise statement you are looking for is proposition 3.3 on page 26 of Danylo Radchenko's doctoral dissertation, [*Higher cross-ratios and geometric functional equations for polylogarithms*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/223015944.pdf) (Rheinischen Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universität Bonn, 2016): the proof of the proposition explains how to view the variables of the invariant field as projected cross-ratios of the points.

Comment: I struggled a bit to find a geometric interpretation of the quantities $\langle \{2\} \mid 1,3,5,4 \rangle$ considered in the reference. Now I understand that this is the cross-ratio of the four lines from $M_1$ to the other points $M_2$, $M_3$, $M_4$ and $M_5$. Fine!